# Powershell Out-File output all on the same line

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that populates a variable, `$Users`, from the contents of a text file using the Get-Content cmdlet.  I then want to append this information to the end of a different text file using Out-File.  However, currently the output is appended all in a row.  What I need is for each string to be on it's own line.

I have tried piping the variable into the `Write-Output` cmdlet and it displays correctly on the screen, but when I redirect it from `Write-Output` back to the `Out-File` cmdlet it appends the information all in a row again.

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Password Reset\Users5.txt"<br>
Out-File -InputObject $Users -FilePath "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Password Reset\RefUsers.txt"
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of Users5.txt?

Comment: Users5.txt is a simple text file a series of usernames 1 listed per line.  Sample input would be:KOP
LLY
NNT
CER5
POK
MIN2
AEA

Comment: Add-Content would be a better fit for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was me I would use `Add-Content` for this with a pipe.

```
$Users = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Password Reset\Users5.txt"
$Users | Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Password Reset\RefUsers.txt"
```

Pay attention to encoding. `Add-Content` uses ascii by default I believe. Also if you are not doing anything with the data you can skip the variable all together.

```
GC "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Password Reset\Users5.txt" | 
    AC "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Password Reset\RefUsers.txt"
```

Gc being an alias for `Get-Content` and Ac for `Add-Content`

Comment: This worked!  Thanks for the suggestion.  I used a Foreach loop instead of piping the information in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how my final script turned out:

$Users = Get-Content "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Password Reset\Users5.txt"
Foreach($U in $Users){
Add-Content "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Password Reset\RefUsers1.txt" "`n$U"
}

Thanks Matt!